# Primeng database numeric edition

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng, primeng-datatable

**NOTE: I'm using primeng 4.3.0**

I've an `Array<AlignedQuote>` where `AlignedQuote` is:

```
interface AlignedQuote {
    hour: number;
    day: number;
    month: number;
    year: number;
}
```

My current related html code is:

```
<p-dataTable [value]="quotes" [editable]="true">
  <p-column *ngFor="let col of cols" [field]="col.field" [header]="col.header"
    [editable]="col.editable">
  </p-column>
</p-dataTable>
```

Where my `cols` is:

```
this.cols = [
  { field: "hour",  header: 'Hora', editable: true  },
  { field: "day",   header: 'Día',  editable: true  },
  { field: "month", header: 'Mes',  editable: true  },
  { field: "year",  header: 'Any',  editable: true  }
];
```

The problem is that I'm able to type string values on each cell editor, and I need to only able to type number values:

[image]

Is it able to constraint it?

It would be nice to wrap each cell edition using an specific numeric cell editor.

**NOTE: I'm using primeng 4.3.0**

Answer (score 0):

There is a custom editor template which you can use.

```
<p-dataTable [value]="quotes" [editable]="true">
      <p-column *ngFor="let col of cols" [field]="col.field" [header]="col.header" [editable]="true">
         <ng-template let-item="rowData" pTemplate="editor">
            <input [(ngModel)]="item[col.field]" type="number">
         </ng-template>
      </p-column>
</p-dataTable>
```

This will allow only number inputs. As you can see it can be easily customized. You can put any content within `<ng-template let-item="rowData" pTemplate="editor">`

[**Stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-template-affwap?)

More examples: [PrimeNG Editable DataTables](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng-4.3.0/#/datatable/editable)